# What does the M stand for in C# Decimal literal notation?

Tags: c#, decimal, literals

In order to work with decimal data types, I have to do this with variable initialization:

```
decimal aValue = 50.0M;
```

What does the M part stand for?

Answer (score 538, accepted):

It means it's a decimal literal, as others have said. However, the origins are probably not those suggested elsewhere in this answer. From the [C# Annotated Standard](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0123725119) (the ECMA version, not the MS version):

> The `decimal` suffix is M/m since D/d
>   was already taken by `double`.
>   Although it has been suggested that M
>   stands for money, Peter Golde recalls
>   that M was chosen simply as the next
>   best letter in `decimal`.

A similar annotation mentions that early versions of C# included "Y" and "S" for `byte` and `short` literals respectively. They were dropped on the grounds of not being useful very often.

Comment: That leaves the question why E/e was not the next best letter.

Comment: "e" would be problematic in that it's already used in literals. For instance "2e4m" is a valid literal (decimal 20000). Even if it were unambiguous (and it may well be, although "1e" ends up with a curious compiler error message suggesting it's out of the range of viable doubles, not that it's syntactically invalid; I suspect that's a bug) it would still be confusing. "c" would possibly make sense without causing any confusion, although it would no doubt suggest "currency" to people :)

Comment: "c" conflicts with the character literal for strings in VB.Net, though even there the grammar is a little different.

Comment: I wouldn't have too much problem with it being different in C# and VB. VB already has different hex syntax for example, IIRC.

Comment: If you lay out the syllables of "Decimal", you get "De Ci Mal". These make the most sense to use. D is already taken, C could be characters, M seems like a logical choice.

Comment: [This list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/value-types-table) is a nice overview including the type suffix for decimal.

Comment: The type of a real literal is determined by its suffix. The literal without suffix or with the d or D suffix is of type double. The literal with the f or F suffix is of type float. The literal with the m or M suffix is of type decimal.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals

Answer (score 129):

From C# specifications:

```cs
var f = 0f; // float
var d = 0d; // double
var m = 0m; // decimal (money)
var u = 0u; // unsigned int
var l = 0l; // long
var ul = 0ul; // unsigned long
```

Note that you can use an uppercase or lowercase notation.

Answer (score 35):

M refers to the first non-ambiguous character in "decimal". If you don't add it the number will be treated as a double.

D is double.

Comment: I suppose there is some important reason, but it irritates me that you get a compile-time error if you leave the m out of the literal. It's not as if it's ambiguous.

Comment: @JSON It works that way for integer types, because there's no ambiguity there - as long as it fits the type, it will not lose/garble any information. The same is not true of decimal numbers. Casting the double value `0.42` to decimal can give you a different value than `0.42M` (and the same for using a double literal in place of a float literal - `float val = 423.3` also fails). So you're choosing between a subtly wrong behavior and a compiler error that takes half a second to fix and conforms to the CLR and C# standards.

Comment: "M", like in "deciMal"

Answer (score 21):

A real literal suffixed by M or m is of type **decimal (money)**. For example, the literals 1m, 1.5m, 1e10m, and 123.456M are all of type decimal. This literal is converted to a decimal value by taking the exact value, and, if necessary, rounding to the nearest representable value using banker's rounding. Any scale apparent in the literal is preserved unless the value is rounded or the value is zero (in which latter case the sign and scale will be 0). Hence, the literal 2.900m will be parsed to form the decimal with sign 0, coefficient 2900, and scale 3.

[Read more about real literals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types#real-literals)

Comment: Thank you for linking to the docs about all of the real literals.

Answer (score 2):

"The letter M was chosen as the most visually distinct letter between the double and decimal keywords."

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tour-of-csharp/tutorials/numbers-in-csharp-local

Answer (score -4):

Well, I guess **M** represent the ***mantissa***. Decimal can be used to save money, but it doesn't mean, decimal only used for money.

Comment: That is indeed a guess, and it's much less plausible than the "first available non-ambiguous character" hypothesis. If you have supporting evidence, include it in your answer.

Comment: I guess the reason for the downvotes here would be that this answer may be quite misleading. The "Mantissa" is the thing that is the difference between the decimal type (not having a mantissa) and the double type (having a mantissa).