# What does the "M" stand for in decimal value assignment?

Tags: c#

MSDN says:

"Without the suffix m, the number is treated as a double, thus generating a compiler error."

What does the "M" in:

```
decimal current = 10.99M;
```

stand for?

Is it any different than:

```
decimal current = (decimal)10.99
```

Comment: Duplicate of... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/c-sharp-decimal-data-type

Comment: It's not a duplicate because it does not address the casting part of the question as Scott does below.

Comment: Skeet said it all I think so no sense in answering this - just one 'help tip' - `if you type that number in the VS (if that's what you're using) - you'll get the info "Represents a Decimal Number". If you type #D or f etc. you'll get different explanations.`

Comment: @NSGaga, as I already stated, Skeet's answer does not address the question of the cast.  Therefore it's not a dup of this question.

Comment: @KirkWoll not saying it is, there's always something to add

Answer (score 35, accepted):

M makes the number a decimal representation in code.

To answer the second part of your question, yes they are different.

```
decimal current = (decimal)10.99
```

is the same as

```
double tmp = 10.99;
decimal current = (decimal)tmp;
```

Now for numbers larger than sigma it should not be a problem but if you meant decimal you should specify decimal.

---

**Update**:

Wow, i was wrong. I went to go check the IL to prove my point and the compiler optimized it away.

---

**Update 2**:

I was right after all!, you still need to be careful. Compare the output of these two functions.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(Test1());
        Console.WriteLine(Test2());
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static decimal Test1()
    {
        return 10.999999999999999999999M;
    }
    static decimal Test2()
    {
        return (decimal)10.999999999999999999999;
    }
}
```

The first returns `10.999999999999999999999` but the seccond returns `11`

---

Just as a side note, double will get you [15 decimal digits of precision](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.aspx#remarksToggle) but decimal will get you [96 bits of precision with a scaling factor from 0 to 28](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx#remarksToggle). So you can represent any number in the range ((-2<sup>96</sup> to 2<sup>96</sup>) / 10<sup>(0 to 28)</sup>)

Comment: Great example! Exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 10):

#### Description

```
decimal current = 10.99M;
```

Tells the compiler you want a decimal number.

```
decimal current = (decimal)10.99
```

Tells the compiler you want to cast your double `10.99` to a decimal.

Some say it stands for **money**. M because you must use decimals in financial applications.
You must use decimals because they are more accurate than floating point numbers (double).

> The decimal suffix is M/m since D/d was already taken by double. Although it has been suggested that M stands for money, Peter Golde recalls that M was chosen simply as the next best letter in decimal.
>
> The decimal has more significant figures than the double, therefore it can be more precise- it also takes up slightly more memory. Other than certian math or physics-related algorithms, the double or float should do fine.

**For example**

- If you do ANYNUMBER / 0.5d you will not get the half of ANYNUMBER.
- If you do ANYNUMBER / 0.5m you will get everytime the half of ANYNUMBER.
- Use `decimal` for money
- Use `double` for exchange rates

#### More Information

- [Decimal vs. Double - difference?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/921a8ffc-9829-4145-bdc9-a96c1ec174a5/)
- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)

Answer (score 2):

Well... I think "D" would be confused with `double`, so... they chose "M"?  Maybe for "Money"?  Seems a bit silly... but I couldn't find anything definitive.

Comment: `M` for the `M` in deci `M` al :-)