# Error CS0029 Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'decimal'

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

```
namespace FitoStore
{
    public partial class FitoStore : Form
    {
        private Dyqan dyqan = new Dyqan();

        public FitoStore()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SetupData();
        }
        private void SetupData()

        {

            dyqan.Shitesit.Add(new Shites { Emeri = "Kujtim", Mbiemeri = "Arishta" });
            dyqan.Shitesit.Add(new Shites { Emeri = "Zaim", Mbiemeri = "Sherbela" });
            dyqan.Produkte.Add(new Produkt {Lloji = "Dap",Kilogram ="25",Cmimi="2.500"});
            dyqan.Produkte.Add(new Produkt {Lloji = "Nitrat",Kilogram="50",Cmimi="2.500"});
        }

    }
 }
```

Comment: Use `decimal.Parse("25")` or simply `Kilogram = 25`

Comment: If your `Kilogram` field is of type decimal, then instead of assigning it a string `"25"` , assign it `25M`, where `M` specifies a number as decimal, or simply `25`.

Comment: not work  @TimSchmelter

Comment: Still is the same error@Habib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
        dyqan.Shitesit.Add(new Shites { Emeri = "Kujtim", Mbiemeri = "Arishta" });
        dyqan.Shitesit.Add(new Shites { Emeri = "Zaim", Mbiemeri = "Sherbela" });
        dyqan.Produkte.Add(new Produkt {Lloji = "Dap",Kilogram =25M,Cmimi=2.500M});
        dyqan.Produkte.Add(new Produkt {Lloji = "Nitrat",Kilogram=50M,Cmimi=2.500M});
```

Where 25M [means](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/what-does-the-m-stand-for-in-c-sharp-decimal-literal-notation) a decimal of value 25.

I've also done it to `Cmimi` as that looks like it should be a decimal. You may need to change it back depending on the type there.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to [mark this as accepted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if this is the solution to your problem. :-)