# What is the relevance of M suffix on a decimal literal

Tags: c#, decimal, literals

```
decimal l = 50.0M;
```

I have seen other answers suggesting that the M is to explicitly state the type as decimal - [What does the M stand for in C# Decimal literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/what-does-the-m-stand-for-in-c-sharp-decimal-literal-notation)

However when the type, of variable, is exclusively stated, why should there be a suffix? I can see the relevance of the suffix when the type, of variable, isn't specified, like:

```
var l = 50.0M
```

Comment: Hi see.. here..https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/what-does-the-m-stand-for-in-c-sharp-decimal-literal-notation

Comment: The answer was [right here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977514/366904), second one down on the question you linked.

Answer (score 6):

> when the type, of variable, is exclusively stated, why should there be a suffix?

You need a cast only in situations when the value that you are assigning has a decimal point. In your case, `50.0` represents a literal of type `double`. You can avoid suffix by adding a cast, like this

```
decimal l = (decimal)50.0; // Do not do this!
```

but this may result in conversion errors:

```
decimal d = (decimal)1.23456789123456789;
Console.WriteLine(d); // Prints 1.23456789123457
decimal e = 1.23456789123456789M;
Console.WriteLine(e); // Prints 1.23456789123456789
```

Note that the following will compile without a suffix or a cast, because `int` to `decimal` conversion never loses precision:

```
decimal l = 50;
```

Another place where you may want `M` suffix is in expressions that manipulate decimals:

```
decimal tenPercentBroken  = myDecimal * 0.1;  // Does not compile
decimal tenPercentCorrect = myDecimal * 0.1M; // Compiles fine
```

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you, I mentioned the reason behind `l=50` working without a cast or a suffix.

Answer (score 1):

`50.0` in C# is a literal `double`, so without the `M` suffix, you are trying to implicitly convert a `double` to a `decimal` (an implicit conversion that does not exist).

Using `decimal l = 50.0M;` says: assign this decimal to that decimal variable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the reason is because the right hand side is evaluated first in assignment statements.

The value on the right hand side is assigned to the variable on the left. So the right hand side has to be evaluated first and then it looks at the left hand side and, if the types are different, it will have to do a cast.

Comment: sounds reasonable!