# C# I set a discount but cant get the price - discount but still original price

Tags: c#, class, methods

```
// here I set the discount which after the subtraction should be 150 euro         
public int SetDiscountPrice()
{
   return price = price -  (10/100)*price;
}
```

and here I call the method `SetDicountPrice` but it does not work

```
Console.WriteLine("\nAfter selling 1 item for {0} euro, number of sofas left is {1}",sofa.SetDiscountPrice(), sofa.SellOneProduct());
```

Comment: what does `(10/100)` give you?

Comment: You need to look at integer & floating point division - 10/100 = 0 use 10.0 / 100.0

Comment: Do you really want an int for a price?

Comment: You need to do arithmetic task with float and then convert it to int

Comment: in the description, it is given as an integer

Comment: You need to divide as float, for instance: 10.0/100.0 = 0.1!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int / int = int` so your calculation would be `x - 0 = x` because `10/100` equals `0`

If you want to calcualte with floating point values use

```
return price = (int)(price - (10m / 100m) * price); // m for decimal type
```

or if you just want to get the value without changing the initial price

```
return (int)(price - (10m / 100m) * price);
```

and think about using type `decimal` for money values

Comment: In case anyone is wondering why `m` stands for `decimal` [have a look here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/977562/2099119).

Comment: I think you may need to cast the calculation to int if that is the return type (clue is in the error message).

Comment: this return statement will not compile. C# compiler will force you to apply an explicit cast...

Comment: @MongZhu: This is why I will finish my career as a C and C++ programmer. I hate all these compulsory explicit conversions in C# and Java.

Comment: @Bathsheba - stick with C/C++ they do more implicit casts, it's C# that requires the explicit casts

Comment: @PaulF: I will!

Comment: @MongZhu I've mentioned both ways - just seems to be bad practice to me

Answer (score 1):

`(10/100)` is an expression equal to 0 due to *integer division*.

Given that you've told us that `price` is an integral type, you ought to use

`return price = price - price / 10;`

and be aware that this will always round up the result. Alternatively, use

`return price = price * 9 / 10;`

which will round downwards, but be mindful that this is vulnerable to integer overflow due to an order of magnitude increase in the `int` during the calculation.

Comment: Naturally ;-)͏͏

Comment: how is this called in c# so I can check it on the Internet

Comment: @АнгелХаджиев - note the order & the bracketing is important - contents of the brackets will be calculated first - so you cannot do _price * (9/10)_ - and with multiply & divide operators having same precedence - the order is left to right - so similarly you cannot do _9 / 10 * price_.

Comment: @PaulF: Yes, I've fallen for `9 / 10 * price` a few times ;-)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

An easy fix would either be casting it to a decimal (Note that price has to be a decimal in that case):

```
return price = price - (decimal)10/100*price;
```

or use a decimal as the divisor:

```
return price = price - 10M/100M*price;
```

you obviously have to adjust your return type as well:

```
public decimal SetDiscountPrice(){
    return price = price - (decimal)10/100*price;
}
```

**Important Information:**

Maybe you should actually overthink your attempt a little bit. A method starting with "Set" sounds like it should be a property and I think it's definitely possible in your case. And are you sure you want your setter-method to change your value and return it at the same time? Maybe following could help you:

```
class YourClass{
    public decimal Price {get; set;}
    public decimal DiscountPrice => (decimal)10/100*Price;
}
```

Comment: same here: `return price = price - (double)10/100*price;` does not compile and neither does `return price = price - 10d/100d*price;`. No implicit converstion!

Comment: Using `double` for money types = very, very naughty especially as C# has a nice shiny built-in decimal type.

Comment: @Bathsheba yeah you're right. I will change it to decimal

Comment: @MongZhu Yep, if price isn't the correct type it obviously won't work. He should use a decimal in this case. If he doesn't care about floating points he should round it.

Comment: in a comment OP states "in the description, it is given as an integer". So I guess it is part of the excersize. #