# Oracle missing expression with a where - query generated by SqlProvider

Tags: oracle, f#, type-providers

I'm trying to query an Oracle database, where the connection is very slow, and the table's rowcount is very high in F# with `SqlDataProvider`. For my purpose I have to use `IQueryable`, so not all the rows are in memory.

The problem is when I add the where clause of the `query` it generates a select which is malformed. It's throwing `'ORA-00936: missing expression'`.

I tried the same thing in MSSQL, and it just works.

```
type sql = SqlDataProvider<Common.DatabaseProviderTypes.ORACLE, "Data Source=localhost;PASSWORD=somePassword;USER ID=someUserId", ResolutionPath="C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017\\odp.net\\managed\\common\\">
let ctx = sql.GetDataContext()

type OrderDTO = { Id: decimal; SomeColumn: string }

[<EntryPoint>]
let main _ = 
    let someList =
        query {
            for order in ctx.Scheme.Tablea do
            // remove the where and it's working
            where (order.Id = 2M)
            take 1
            select { Id = order.Id; SomeColumn = order.SomeColumn }
        }
    // missing expression thrown next line
    let firstItem =
        someList
        |> Seq.head
    printfn "%A" firstItem
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Installation details:

> .NET Framework 4.7.1
>
> <package id="FSharp.Core" version="4.6.2" targetFramework="net471"
>   />
>  <package id="FSharp.Data" version="3.0.1"
>   targetFramework="net471" />
>  <package id="SQLProvider"
>   version="1.1.50" targetFramework="net471" />
>  <package
>   id="System.ValueTuple" version="4.4.0" targetFramework="net471" />

At `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2017"` there is a ODAC for VS 2017 18.3.0.0 installed.

Oracle version:

> Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit
>   Production
>  PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>   CORE  11.2.0.2.0  Production
>  TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version
>   11.2.0.2.0 - Production
>  NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production

Table definition:

> CREATE TABLE "SCHEME"."TABLEA" 
>     (   "ID" NUMBER(*,0), 
>     "SOME_COLUMN" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
>     "SOME_COLUMN2" VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) 
>     )

How can I fix the where?
The generated query is the following:

`select * from (SELECT order.ID as "ID",order.SOME_COLUMN as "SOME_COLUMN" FROM SCHEME.TABLEA order WHERE ((order.ID = :param1))) where ROWNUM <= 1 -- params :param1 - 2M;`

Comment: I don't know tools you use, but - if it is about the WHERE clause, try to use single quotes (as dealing with a string): `where (order.Id = '2M')`

Comment: Thank you for tip. I'm using f#'s type providers. To be more specific the `SQLProvider`, which is strongly typed. The provider does it's ORM thing, and the `order.Id` in the where clause is already `decimal`, so I can't write `string` there

Comment: Sorry, it's just that `2M` looked like a string to me (still does, to be honest).

Comment: Oh. That's just decimal literal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/what-does-the-m-stand-for-in-c-sharp-decimal-literal-notation

Comment: Aha. I see; thank you. I'm afraid I can't help. Hopefully, someone else will be able to assist. Good luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug the query, hook SqlQueryEvent. Here's some code I used for that:

```
let logSqlEvent eventData =
    eventData
    |> sprintf "Executing SQL: %O"
    |> Debug.WriteLine

QueryEvents.SqlQueryEvent 
|> Event.add logSqlEvent
```

If your query works for SQL Server, but not Oracle, there's a good chance it's a bug. When I did some Access queries with SQLProvider a while back, I found bugs in the generated queries. I fixed them and submitted PRs - that's actually pretty easy to do.

Comment: yes. I finally was able to debug the query with `FSharp.Data.Sql.Common.QueryEvents.SqlQueryEvent |> Event.add (printfn "Executing SQL: %O")` . Now I see it's generating the `;` after the `--`. So the closing of the select is commented out

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the following Issue: https://github.com/fsprojects/SQLProvider/issues/595

I used the order keyword in the query. Seemingly the problem is because the generated query contained a comment, which after the semicolon came, but it's not problem.