# Not allowing 0.00 decimal places ( Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio, decimal

I am confused at why its saying "literal of type cannot be implicity converted to type 'decimal'; use 'M' suffix. Unsure what use "'M'" is

```
        private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        decimal decTotal = 0.00;
        decimal decTotalAfterDiscount;
        bool bolRadioChecked = false;

        if (chkHygienistTreatment.Checked == true) ;
        {
            decTotal = 119.50;
        }
        if (chkCheckupexam.Checked == true) ;
        {
            decTotal += 100;
        }
        if (chkCrecefilling.Checked == true) ;
        {
            decTotal += 126.30;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should change your code like this:

```
decimal decTotal = 0.00m;
```

because if you don't use the "m" the compiler doesn't understand that it should be treated as a decimal. that's how c# works.

Answer (score 0):

In C#

```
0.00
```

Is a `double` literal. Which cannot be implicitly※ converted into `decimal`, because there are values representable in `double` that are not representable in `decimal`.

※: Implicitly meaning without an explicit cast (i.e. `(decimal)0.00`). Explicit cast may throw. Although a cast won't throw for this particular value.

You can add a "M" or "m" to the literal to make it a `decimal` literal instead:

```
0.00m
```

See also [What does the M stand for in C# Decimal literal notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/what-does-the-m-stand-for-in-c-sharp-decimal-literal-notation).