# Get how many decimal digits there is after a dot

Tags: c#

I want to calculate the number of digits after the decimal point of a decimal number. My program works, but it returns the wrong number when I add more digits, for example, `5.55266666666555555` has 17 digits after the decimal point, but my program returns only 15.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result is: {0}", howMuchDots(5.55266666666555555));
    }

    static double howMuchDots(double num)
    {
        /* Convert num to string, split it with dot into an array, and take the second cell. Then get the length of the string */
        return num.ToString().Split(".")[1].Length;
    }
}
```

I tried to use `float` instead, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Double only has about 15-17 digits precision: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types

Comment: @SomeBody Yeah that is what I thought, then, why should I do?

Comment: Note that formatting the double into a string will often do some simplification. Use the "G17" format to see all of the gory details. That won't help if you're pushingthe limits of double precision however

Comment: Since you're dealing with numbers accurate to many significant figures, and you need to accurately represent numbers in base 10 (without the changes that converting to base 2 adds), it would probably be better to use `decimal` rather than `double`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/GgMPe7

Comment: Probably not relevant in this context, but consider also that a ToString on a floating point number inserts the decimal separator for the current culture and not all cultures uses the . to separate the decimal part. On my machine, for example, your code fails at the split call. Because there is no point but a comma to split on

Comment: @canton7 Why should I use `decimal`? It is an Integer, no? It gives me an error when I give a decimal number as an argument to the function.

Comment: @zer0-padding `decimal` is not an integer, no. See the link in my last comment, when I demonstrate it being used

Comment: Fun fact, how c# will display a floating point value (no matter how your format it) and what it actually is are sometimes 2 different things. In that respect this question becomes nearly futile

Comment: What is the expected result if the `decimal` is 1.0000000m?

Comment: @mjwills Probably the amount of zeros in the decimal literal, I guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, the difference between the float, double and decimal data types lies in the precision and therefore also in how much memory is used to hold them. The float is the least expensive one - it can represent a number with up to 7 digits. The double is more precise, with up to 16 digits, while the decimal is the most precise, with a whooping maximum of 29 digits.

You just need to change the type of your argument to decimal.

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Result is: {0}", howMuchDots(5.55266666666555555m));
    }

    static int howMuchDots(decimal num)
    {
        var length = (num - Math.Truncate(num)).ToString().Length - 2;
        return length > 0 ? length : 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the limits of precision for float and double aren't hard limits -- you get between around 6 to 9 digits of precision for a float for example, depending on the exact number you're trying to represent.

Comment: While true statement how it relates to the question - "how much decimal numbers there is after a dot"... I.e. some good words could be written for 1.234567e10 - does it have 6 number after dot or zero...

Comment: Hey, it doesn't work for me. `Cannot convert from double to decimal`.

Comment: @zer0-padding: Call it with `howMuchDots(5.55266666666555555m)`

Comment: @SomeBody What does the `m` represent?

Comment: @zer0-padding How about casting to string and dealing with strings inside your method?

Comment: @zer0-padding https://stackoverflow.com/questions/977484/what-does-the-m-stand-for-in-c-sharp-decimal-literal-notation

Comment: This answer has some problems. First it assumes that the dot is the separator and this is not always the case, then it doesn't deal with numbers that doesn't have decimals. Third, Split with just a single string parameter doesn't work on NET Framework (works in core or net5)

Comment: Yes, this answer is flawed in several ways.

Comment: @mjwills It is accurate up to 28 decimal numbers

Comment: Let's hope that number isn't negative. ;)

Comment: And what about 1.00000000000000001? Calling ToString on certain double inevitably rounds and truncates some part or the number. Even with the sample number provided by the asker you should get as result 17 but this code returns 15.

Comment: If you try your example, the result would be 17. `num` is not a double but a decimal

Comment: I see, tried with double as OP posted initially

Answer (score 3):

You say you want to use a decimal but your method takes a double.

Assuming you actually want to use a decimal this works. Try using [GetBits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.getbits?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Decimal_GetBits_System_Decimal_) method to convert several Decimal values to their equivalent binary representations.

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp7
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            decimal[] decimalValues = { 1M, 100000000000000M, 10000000000000000000000000000M,
                100000000000000.00000000000000M, 1.0000000000000000000000000000M,
                123456789M, 0.123456789M, 0.000000000123456789M,
                0.000000000000000000123456789M, 4294967295M,
                18446744073709551615M, decimal.MaxValue,
                decimal.MinValue, -7.9228162514264337593543950335M, 5.55266666666555555M };

            foreach (var num in decimalValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{num} Result is: {howMuchDots(num)}");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
        static double howMuchDots(decimal num)
        {
            return  (decimal.GetBits(num)[3] >> 16) & 0x000000FF;
        }
    }
}
```