# Emit IL code to load a decimal value

Tags: c#, .net, reflection.emit, il

I have code like this to emit IL code that loads integer or string values. But I don't know how to add the `decimal` type to that. It isn't supported in the `Emit` method. Any solutions to this?

```
ILGenerator ilGen = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
if (type == typeof(int))
{
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, Convert.ToInt32(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
else if (type == typeof(double))
{
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_R8, Convert.ToDouble(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
else if (type == typeof(string))
{
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldstr, Convert.ToString(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

Not working:

```
else if (type == typeof(decimal))
{
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ld_???, Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
}
```

---

**Edit:** Okay, so here's what I did:

```
else if (type == typeof(decimal))
{
    decimal d = Convert.ToDecimal(value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
    // Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb1c1a6x.aspx
    var bits = decimal.GetBits(d);
    bool sign = (bits[3] & 0x80000000) != 0;
    byte scale = (byte)((bits[3] >> 16) & 0x7f);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[0]);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[1]);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[2]);
    ilGen.Emit(sign ? OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 : OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, scale);
    var ctor = typeof(decimal).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(int), typeof(bool), typeof(byte) });
    ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
}
```

But it doesn't generate a `newobj` opcode, but instead `nop` and `stloc.0`. The constructor is found and passed to the `Emit` call. What's wrong here? Obviously an `InvalidProgramException` is thrown when trying to execute the generated code because the stack is completely messed up.

Comment: Apparently (but don't take my word for it) for "load decimal" there isn't a direct opcode, you load the arguments and call the decimal constructor: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/485834/266143

Comment: See also http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2014/08/22/when-is-a-constant-not-a-constant-when-its-a-decimal/. In short: decimals are not CLR primitive types and there's no IL opcode for loading one directly.

Comment: See my edit above for a non-working solution.

Comment: I think this line is wrong: `ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, scale)`. You're saying you're loading an I4 (`int`), but then use the `byte` overload of `Emit()`. One way to fix that would be `ilGen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, (int)scale);`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Come on, just decompile some C# code that does the same thing - you'll see that there's no decimal primitive.

```
42M
```

compiles to

```
ldc.i4.s    2A
newobj      System.Decimal..ctor
```

For a decimal number, this is *much* more complicated:

```
42.3M
```

gives

```
ldc.i4      A7 01 00 00 
ldc.i4.0    
ldc.i4.0    
ldc.i4.0    
ldc.i4.1    
newobj      System.Decimal..ctor
```

The easiest way to get this for an arbitrary decimal is to use the `int[]` overload of the constructor and the `GetBits` static method. You could also reverse-engineer the `SetBits` method to allow you to call the simpler constructor with the proper values, or use reflection to read the internal state - there's plenty of options.

**EDIT:**

You're close, but you broke the ILGen - while the last argument to the constructor is a `byte`, the constant you're loading *must* be an `int`. The following works as expected:

```
var bits = decimal.GetBits(d);
bool sign = (bits[3] & 0x80000000) != 0;
int scale = (byte)((bits[3] >> 16) & 0x7f);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[0]);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[1]);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[2]);
gen.Emit(sign ? OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1 : OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, scale);
var ctor = typeof(decimal).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(int), typeof(int), 
                                                typeof(int), typeof(bool), typeof(byte) });
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, ctor);
gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

**EDIT 2:**

A simple example of how you can use expression trees (in this case the tree is built by the C# compiler, but that's up to you) to define dynamic method bodies:

```
var assembly = AssemblyBuilder.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"), 
                                                     AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run);
var module = assembly.DefineDynamicModule("Test");
var type = module.DefineType("TestType");

var methodBuilder = type.DefineMethod("MyMethod", MethodAttributes.Public 
                                                  | MethodAttributes.Static);
methodBuilder.SetReturnType(typeof(decimal));

Expression<Func<decimal>> decimalExpression = () => 42M;

decimalExpression.CompileToMethod(methodBuilder);

var t = type.CreateType();

var result = (decimal)t.GetMethod("MyMethod").Invoke(null, new object[] {});

result.Dump(); // 42 :)
```

Comment: This is apparently because _"The Extended Numerics Library"_ is not part of the CIL specification, because _"some commonly available
processors do not provide direct support for the data types"_ (source: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-335.pdf, large PDF). That's why there's no opcode for loading a `decimal` (nor a `single`).

Comment: Thanks for the clues. Unfortunately it still doesn't work properly. See my edit in the question.

Comment: @LonelyPixel Updated with the correct code - `ldc.i4` *must* be passed an `int`. It's a shame that ILGen will let you do this, but you just have to be careful :) However, you don't really need ILGen all that much nowadays - why not use `Expression.Compile`?

Comment: @LonelyPixel Or, to clear up the confusion, of course ILGen doesn't catch that error - it doesn't do any validation at all. It simply emits bytes - that's it. Your decompiler then tells you that the `newobj` wasn't emitted, but that isn't actually true - the problem is that the `ldc.i4` before that `newobj` was three bytes shorter than it should have been. I hope that clears up the confusion somehow :) ILGen will always be extremely fragile - it does very little besides translating opcodes and constants into IL bytes.

Comment: Thanks, changing it to `int` made it work. The whole system is using a dynamic assembly and `TypeBuilder` so it needs to be extended that way. But now everything's fine.

Comment: @LonelyPixel Actually, you can use an expression tree to build a method body - that's what the `CompileToMethod` method is for :)

Comment: @LonelyPixel I've added an example of how to do this. There are some limitations, but if you can work within them, you're going to save yourself a lot of trouble in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As Luaan mentioned before, you can use the `decimal.GetBits` method and the `int[]` constructor. Have a look at this example:

```
public static decimal RecreateDecimal(decimal input)
{
    var bits = decimal.GetBits(input);

    var d = new DynamicMethod("recreate", typeof(decimal), null);
    var il = d.GetILGenerator();

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_4);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(int));

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[0]);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[1]);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_2);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[2]);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Dup);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_3);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, bits[3]);
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Stelem_I4);

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(decimal).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(int[])}));

    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
    return (decimal) d.Invoke(null, null);
}
```